# How do I change the format of my date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I have a field called StartDate in my tables that look like the following,

1977-10-17 00:00:00.000

how do I change those values to represent 10-17-1977?  Also, if the date is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 I want to change it to null value.  Is there a command or stored procedure for these types of changes?

thanks
Nick

Comment: What datatype is the StartDate column?

Comment: 1. CONVERT function. 2.CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the format you're after, as in:

```
select convert(varchar(10), MyColumn, 110) from MyTable;
```

Here we're converting your datetime to a character value, but with a particular date style (style 110).

Your null issue can be sorted with a [`case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) switch or with the [`nullif`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select nullif(MyColumn, '19000101') from MyTable;
select case when MyColumn = '19000101' then null else MyColumn end from MyTable;
```

Note that I'm assuming `MyColumn` is stored as a datetime or similar datatype. If not, then you can `cast` them as such according to the above documentation.

Feel free to combine functions, as in:

```
select convert(varchar(10), nullif(MyColumn, '19000101'), 110) from MyTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
declare @date varchar(10)
set @date = CONVERT(varchar(10),@startdate,110)
```

Comment: 101 returns date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format OP wants it to be in `mm-dd-yyyy` format, also your solution doesn't deal with sql server default date case.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  StartDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN NULL
         ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate , 110)
       END AS StartDate 

FROM Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show the time with the date format requested try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) + substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121),12,12)
```

For a comparative listing of the different formats for dates with the CONVERT command, use the code at http://rossql.blogspot.com/2014/04/sql-format-of-date-and-time-way-i-like.html